# Multiple Authors on a Single Blog

Tags: author, blog

I'm currently researching into using WordPress and so, apologies in advance if this seems like a very basic question.

Our main requirement is to have a single blog, but allow multiple users / authors (essentially the entire organization which could be up to 100 people) to post.

Is this possible in WordPress?

We would be hosting WordPress within our organization (e.g. in an intranet environment).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation on the amount of users... There are some great plugins
that would help you manage permissions and limitation you might want to empose
to avoid problems..

Tip: Aritcle writers should a writer user level

1. [Email Users Plugin](http://www.marvinlabs.com/products-and-references/wordpress-addons/email-users/) - This would help you send email to all users in one click.
2. [WyPiekacz](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wypiekacz/) - A very good plugin! would help you set a minimun post length, maximum amount of categories and tags and more..

Hope This helps,
Sagive

Comment: glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. There is no limit (in theory) to the number of users. You'd probably want to look at the user roles to give different people the proper amount of access.